# DDNS with No-IP does not work

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, ddns, noip

I want to access my home machine from internet. Since I don't have a static IP I am trying to use DDNS. For that, I've registered a free domain(alihammad.ddns.net) with Noip.com, it binds my external IP (101.50.xx.x) with the domain name. I've also configured my router DDNS settings

Router: TP-Link TL-WR740N
Routeer Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (11/21/10) std

[image]

I am also forwarding two ports, 80 for web and 22 for ssh. 
[image]

Now if I ping my domain (alihammad.ddns.net) from LAN, it works. But, if I ping the same domain from another network, it doesn't work.

Please guide?

Comment: You can't ping because you only forwarded 80 and 22.  The ping stops at the router, as it should.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing failed pings is that DD-WRT blocks anonymous ping requests by default (any competent router should do this as well). It helps to prevent people from "seeing" you on the internet, therefore improving your security a little bit.

You'll likely need to open and forward ports, depending on what you're planning on doing.

Comment: Any way to unblock it?

Comment: @Ali Sure, but I'd highly go against this. It's in the `Security` page. Untick `Block Anonymous WAN Requests (ping)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found your solution, but for people looking for an answer:

When you forward a port on your router, you need to specify the IP of the device which host the service. In your forwarding table you use 192.168.53.1 which is the router IP.

So if your Web server is on 192.168.53.10, you should use this address.
Also to be sure that the device keeps the same IP address, you should use the MAC/IP binding.

In order to know your IP address/ MAC address:
Windows: Win + R, execute "cmd" (or "cmd.exe"), and type "ipconfig" press enter.
Mac/Linux: launch a terminal, and type "ifconfig" press enter.